# warn about voting on old information

Tags: feature-request, voting, edits

I ran into the situation where I made a down-vote on what turned out to be an old version of an answer that was displayed in my browser. By the time I realized the answer had been completely edited to remove the inaccurate information, it was too late to cancel my vote.

While I probably should have refreshed before voting, it would be nice if a user were warned that the post being voted on has been edited or if the vote were not accepted until the user reloaded the page so as to avoid such a case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be useful. As a work-around in the mean time you could add a comment and ask the user to edit the answer again so that you can change your vote.  Explain the situation and possibly even link to the meta post.

Comment: I did that very thing ^_^

Comment: Do you think the poster would edit again if someone wanted to remove an upvote executed in a similar situation, though? ^_^

Comment: @jswolf19, in the reverse situation it is less likely that a poster would edit the question.  But in that case you would be leaving a comment about corrections that are needed.   Plus once you get to 2000 rep you can edit the post yourself if you need to change your vote.

Comment: I think it more likely that the OP changes the question to make the answer less applicable, myself, but I guess I mean that the page having old information is a more general problem than just the downvoting situation I provided. I know that it's next to impossible to ensure up-to-date info using http, but I don't always remember to refresh the page after checking out links or other resources or thinking about a solution for an extended period of time (although I'm getting better at that). Maybe by the time I get up to the 2000 rep, I'll be in the habit ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you post incorrect information you have to expect downvotes. If you later edit the answer to correct it you can't really expect that all the downvoters will check it again to remove their downvotes.

So I don't think it's a huge problem. If you posted something incorrect you basically deserve the downvotes, even if you then later correct the answer.

Comment: I'm just giving my personal example. What if the opposite (albeit harder to imagine actually happening) situation occurs, someone upvoted a post that was good in it's pre-revised form but had been edited to a new, less acceptable form between the voter's loading of the page and placing the vote. Then there is an undeserved upvote on incorrect information that the voter knows to be incorrect but can't change his/her vote.

Comment: @jswolf: In that case the voter could still leave a comment, explaining the problems with the post, which probably will bring other people to downvote it. But the problem is more general there: There could be many upvotes on a post that is then later changed to a different content. The upvotes would still be there since none of the voters will realize that the content has changed. But I think that these problems happen rarely enough to not be a real problem.

Comment: I admit that I don't consider it a high-priority feature, but there are often times that I get bitten from info changing between my loading of a page and committing an action on that page, and the warning of new answers is such a nice feature that I feel further such warnings would be a good thing. I don't like downvoting, myself (partially because I don't like being downvoted ^_^), and I would rather encourage the correction of bad information by removing my downvote, especially if it was done before I committed my vote (though I don't suggest that everyone should do/feel the same.)